# gwt connection between clients

Tags: gwt, connection, client

I’m very new to gwt developing and I would like to know, if it is possible to change client information’s from another client. I would like to do following;
Person A adds a new car to a list, this modification should also add automatically to another client (website).  Is that possible with gwt? Right now, I’m just having the idea to use a solution with a SQL database.  Is there a way to connect two websites?
Greet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that directly from client to client.
You will have to implement it via a backend (not necessarily a SQL Server).
Client A sends the modifications/data to the backend.

In order for Client B to see the update you can rely on two different techniques:

1. Pull by polling via a Timer (easy to implement)
2. Push either by Websockets or Comet (check out [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) project)
3. Push via event based service (check out [gwteventservice](http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/) project)

Comment: How could the backend looks like? It is my first time :) Do you have any example? Thanks. Greetz.

Comment: The backend is the "server" part of GWT, ie. the serlets.

Comment: It depends on what kind of Backend you want to use. If you use ``RequestBuilder``you can use any kind of backend (PHP,ruby,node.js,Java).  If you want to use ``RPC``or ``RequestFactory``you will probably use a ``JAVA``backend (i.e. servlets in the simplest case) or a full ``JAVA`` framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will have a look for at the RPC method.